# A technical term for constrained motion resembling that of a snake

Tags: single-word-requests, technical

Imagine a point moving along a curve. This point is simply *traversing* the curve, I suppose.

But now imagine a little "curve-segment" moving along the same curve, while conforming to the curve at all times. So no part of the curve-segment ever strays from the greater curve.

Now forget about the greater curve and focus on the moving curve-segment. What word describes this motion?

It moves [like a snake](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zEto1-ZTbd4), or like the [wire on a bicycle brake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bowden_cable), but I'm hoping for a word in the register of [*Reciprocate*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocating_motion) and [*Articulated*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Articulated_vehicle), not *Slither*. The word can refer to either the motion (verb) or the constraint (adverb or adjective), whatever is most suggestive of the constrained nature of the motion.

EDIT: I should add that the curve need not necessarily be curvy. It just *may* be straight by coincidence. Therefore the emphasis is on the conformity between motion and shape.

EDIT2: Another example: Picture the way a train moves, but forget about the tracks (to avoid words like *Ride*).

Comment: Perhaps it is ***undulating***.  maybe it’s even *conformal undulation*.

Comment: 'serpentine' is literally like a snake. Did you check a thesaurus for similar?

Comment: @Mitch I did but those synonyms tend to emphasize the curvyness whereas I just used a snake as a generic example to avoid the narrow scope of a straight rod moving along its own axis.

Comment: I would suggest 'flagellate' as a scientific verb, but am unable to find this exact meaning with that word in any dictionary... It is however the first technical term that came to mind.

Comment: If the question is not about snake-like movement, then why does the title ask for movement resembling a snake? This is confusing. Do you just want 'the segment is __following__ the curve'?

Comment: @Mitch If you have a better idea for a title I should have used, please suggest it. But the emphasis should be on an elongated (and possibly curved) object moving in a way that is *constrained by the same greater curve to which physically conforms*. I thought *snaking* wasn't a bad example to start with, as long as I clarify that it is just one of multiple possible scenarios.

Comment: Could you add three example sentences (one for the verb, one each for adver/adjective)?

Comment: Your own term "conform" works, and is in the same register as your sample terms *reciprocate* and *articulated*. For [tag:single-word-requests], please click the tag itself and then the [learn more](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) link in it to see the checklist to follow for this category of questions. This includes things like including a sample sentence so that we know *how* you intend to use the word. In turn, this helps the community provide answers that better fit what you have in mind.

Comment: "I'm hoping for a word in the register of Reciprocate and Articulated". How about *emulate*, then. The segment with local support emulates the time-shifted signal.

Comment: It slides along a path.  Not snake-like at all.

Comment: It **follows** or **tracks** the path/curve ?

Comment: @TK-421 Flagellate means to whip, so not sure it is the right word here!

Comment: adheres to a circumscribed path

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have found the best answer yourself: *Constrained* is used to mean something similar, including by you, though you'd have to make it clear that your snake is constrained to the curve. Refer to the snake as a *(curve) segment* and you wouldn't have to, but then you need to be clear not to imply a part of the original curve, but something following it. The curve it follows might be described as a *path*

*Guided* might also be of interest, though it feels like it should apply to an animate entity rather than a simple object.

I doubt you'll find a perfect single word, but with the right context at first you can probably refer to the constraints in subsequent mentions. Perhaps you could even define *path-constrained*, as the unusual term makes it clear that you're not referring to arbitrary constraints. In fact [path-constraint](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/3ds-max/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2017/ENU/3DSMax/files/GUID-FC720C8E-0015-4D86-AC09-AD122EDC7929-htm.html) is used in this context in the CAD world.

Comment: +1 "path" Is a general concept including curves and/or straight segments. Someone used ithis construction at https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/97728/best-way-to-constrain-character-to-a-path&ved=2ahUKEwj6kpjx7PzoAhVYH7kGHfnSD-YQFjADegQIBRAB&usg=AOvVaw0SREzMGwussDsuRI8yePXJ&cshid=1587586734915

Answer (score -2):

I'll focus on the perceived quality of all parts following in a given (if previously unseen) track, while neglecting any allusions to a specific way of movement:

To troop: Assumes multiple objects moving in a coherent manner along a common path.

To flock: As troop, but with less internal order, also usually towards some point.

To file: As troop, but with a definite, simple, order.

To journey: As troop, but possible for a single object.